# Sublime Text SFTP not connecting to ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance, sftp, sublimetext

I am dealing with connecting to my ubuntu EC2 instance. I am unable to connect with my instance using SFTP. My sftp-config.json file is as follows:
{
"type": "sftp",

```
"host": "ec2 ip",
"user": "ubuntu",
"remote_path": "/home/ubuntu",
"ssh_key_file": "C:/Users/example/keypair/keypair.ppk",
//"password": "password",
"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/example/path/",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
```

I am unable to understand what is the problem. I am also using a ppk file with version 2. And also I am able to successfully connect to my instance using filezilla.

SFTP is showing the following error:

```
Connecting to SFTP server "ec2 ip" as "ubuntu" ......................... failure (Connection timeout)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thank you

UPDATE:
I HAVE ANSWERED THE QUESTION.

Comment: another way to do this is to mount your remote folder in ```/etc/fstab``` with ```sshfs``` and work in the mounted folder in sublime... home it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured out what to do.
Instead of using a private key to connect to the server. It is better to use openSSH server and SSH.
This worked for me and it is way more better than using a private key.
You can see the following tutorial to install and connect to the server using SFTP.

[The Tutorial](https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/709d3c777407ab658aa9)

Some things I should mention are:

1. Use port 22 only. No other port worked for me.
2. Login using your instance Public IP and username as: sftp_user.
3. Use the remote path for config-sftp.json as '/data/'.

For more help you can always reply to this comment.